# What is the .vs folder used for in Visual Studio solutions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

What is the .vs folder used for exactly? It gets created at the base folder of my solution. I can see some hidden files and different files appear for different projects. I'm having a hard time chasing up official documentation on it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Even though there is no specific documentation, there was a similar question **[`here`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/82249/vs-folder.html)**

Usually, **`.vs`** folder is required by Visual Studio to store opened documents, breakpoints, and other information about state of your solution.  which means It contains typical files like,

- Temporary caches used by Roslyn for IntelliSense.
- IIS Express applicationHost.config file.
- Many other possible files (you are welcome to edit this answer to include what you know of).

Comment: From [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/82249/vs-folder.html) I take it?

Comment: @john yes provided link

Answer (score 13):

While not a direct answer to this question, I thought I'd share that I recently had an issue in my ASP.Net Core website where routing appeared to be completely broken with no code changes. What's more, I tried deleting views/razor pages and it was still incorrectly loading an old view, presumably cached. But whenever I switched to the console launch setting, the issue went away.

I then recalled that in rare cases the .vs folder can sometimes cause IIS Express to become corrupt, so I closed VS, deleted the .vs folder, re-started and launched the website with the IIS setting and everything worked again.

Answer (score 4):

Similarly to santos, this is not a direct answer to this question but I have found that deleting the .vs folder can sometimes get you out of trouble when all else fails!

See this question that I asked a year ago for an example of where deleting this folder fixed the problem of duplicate tests that were showing up for me in Visual studio
[Visual Studio 2019 showing duplicate tests in Test Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304323/visual-studio-2019-showing-duplicate-tests-in-test-explorer/60304423#60304423)