# Is it safe to ignore .VS folder?

Tags: c#, git, github, project

While working on GITHUB on a Visual Studio project, the .vs folder is painful. So, I want to ignore the folder in .gitignore.Is it safe to ignore .vs?

I tried to do it and it seemed to work. But still need some suggestion on this matter.

Comment: _"the .vs folder is painful"_ You should choose VisualStudio .gitignore template in the first place.

Comment: .vs folder keeps information like application hosting configuration, and user preferences (like VS Packages, open solution explorer or not on project loading, color preferences, etc.). Hosting configuration is an important file because VS read IIS config from here sp I think this should not be Ignored. You can read more from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897191/what-is-the-vs-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio-solutions#:~:text=vs%20folder%20is%20required%20by,IIS%20Express%20applicationHost.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the `.vs` folder can be ignored by (and should never have been added to) source control.

It contains various user-specific and session-specific things that Visual Studio uses when running on any given workstation.  It **does not** contain anything needed for building the application itself.  It's even likely to be different for different users on different workstations, and there's no reason multiple users should share its information.

I suppose it's possible, though don't have a specific reference at the moment, that it could also end up containing something that is in some way needed but still **shouldn't** be kept in source control.  "User secrets" are a common example.  In cases like that, such as when a connection string or service account is needed to run the application, such things should generally be kept securely and not in source control.