# Visual Studio 2019 showing duplicate tests in Test Explorer

Tags: unit-testing, testing, duplicates, visual-studio-2019, test-explorer

Duplicate Unit Tests started showing up for me in Visual Studio 2019, which I recently upgraded from 2017.
I’ve a side by side comparison of Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 below, which shows some test were duplicated and categorised under tests not run:  [image]

Cleaning the solution didn’t get rid of these tests and the only thing that did, was deleting the git repository and cloning it again.

[image]

Has anybody come across this issue and have a better solution that this sledge hammer approach?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was talking to a colleague who also came across the same issue and he suggested another solution that worked for him.

- Close Visual Studio.
- **Delete the ".vs" folder**. You will find this folder where your solution (.sln) file exists.
- Open Visual Studio.

This resolved the issue for him and is a less drastic measure that a delete and clone.

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thanks!