# Visual Studio Build only working in Admin Mode

Tags: visual-studio

I have Installed Visual studio 2019 and 2017 in my Windows 10 machine. I can build application only if i open VS in admin Mode. I have to run my app using different credentials to connect to DB, in this scenario i cant run VS in admin mode. Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Subbiah K

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you're not admin?

Comment: You *impersonate another user*, you're not just running as a normal user. That's completely different. How did you impersonate that other user? And why try to *build* the application as another user? Is the *real* question "How can I debug an impersonated user"?

Comment: Build Failed with 0 errors. Seems access denied issue.

Comment: Simple console app is not building, Recently i have upgrade my laptop. Its building in admin mode not in regular mode.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to run visual studio as a specific user as you need to test using different credentials. If so, try adding those user accounts as power users to the machine and you should be able to run it.

Comment: Forget about the special user, i want to Build the app in regular mode which means without elevated privilleges.

Comment: Ok. See if this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239325/how-to-find-reason-of-failed-build-without-any-error-or-warning

Also sometimes installation order of editors may cause problem. I assume that you installed 2017 first and then 2019