# Visual studio compiling failed without any errors

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile my shell sort program, and it is failing. Visual studio shows no errors, only text: ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========. What could be cause of that? At now I tried to change the loop order and no luck so far.
I am using the latest visual studio 2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


struct dati
{
    int len = 6;
    int* mas = new int[len];
    int* mas1 = new int[len / 2];
    int* mas2 = new int[len / 2];
    dati()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            cout << "enter arrays " << i << ". element:";
            cin >> mas[i];
        }
    }
};

void shella(dati *ret)
{

    int d = ret->len/2;
    int* temp2 = new int[ret->len];

    for (int i = 0; i < ret->len; i++)
    {
        if (ret->len > ret->len / 2)
        {
            ret->mas1[i] = ret->mas[i];
        }
        else
            ret->mas2[i] = ret->mas[i];
    }

    int *temp = new int[ret->len];

    for (int i = 0; i < ret->len; i++)
    {
        if (ret->len > ret->len / 2)
        {
            temp[i] = ret->mas1[i];
        }
        else
            temp[i] = ret->mas2[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ret->len; i++)
    {
        if (ret->len > ret->len / 2)
        {
            ret->mas1[i] = temp[i];
        }
        else
            ret->mas2[i] = temp[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ret->len; i++)
    {
        if (ret->len > ret->len / 2)
        {
            ret->mas1[i] = temp[i];
        }
        else
            ret->mas2[i] = temp[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ret->len/2 - 1; i++)
    {
        if (ret->mas1[i] > ret->mas1[i + 1])
            swap(ret->mas1[i], ret->mas1[i + 1]);

        if (ret->mas2[i] > ret->mas2[i + 1])
            swap(ret->mas2[i], ret->mas2[i + 1]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ret->len / 2; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            temp2[i] = ret->mas1[i];
        else
            temp2[i] = ret->mas2[i];
    }

    int a = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a != 1000; a++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ret->len - 1; i++)
        {
            if (temp2[i] > temp2[i + 1])
                swap(temp2[i], temp2[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ret->len; i++)
    {
        cout << temp2[i] << "\t";
    }

    delete[] temp2;
    delete[] temp;
    system("pause");
}

int main()
{
    dati *ret;

    ret = new dati();

    shella(ret);
}
```

Comment: Please post your error message and [MRE]

Comment: There is no error messages. Just ```
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========```

Comment: Try cleaning up the solution and rebuild

Comment: what window are you talking about `Error List` or `Output`?

Comment: Output window. There's 0 errors. About rebuilding, have tried that

Comment: I suppose that's not the code you compiled? There is no main and no includes, for all the standard library functions. It's impossible to help if we can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my post. Not there's all the code from my project

Comment: There may be some things in the answers here to try: [How to find reason of failed Build without any error or warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13239325/6610379)

Comment: Well, Thank you for that link, I had to delete .vs map to compile my code successfully. #VisualStudio